# How to use XPath-Functions like exists() in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath-2.0, xpathnavigator

I want to read some Nodes from a XmlDocument-Object using the SelectNodes-Method and the XPathNavigator-Class.

But C# is unable to evaluate this (validated with XMLSpy) XPath-Expressen:

```
//LogicUnit[exists(Level[@val = 'R'])]/LogicLines[exists(LogicLine/DATAVIEW_SRC)]
```

The Runtime throws the XPAthException "*Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.*"

I don't understand this exception because my XML-Document doesn't use any Namespaces and there is also no XSLT-Document. This exception always appears if I'm using any XPATH-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that it can't use functions without a namespace manager, however, you don't need to use functions, and your code is using that function in the wrong way. you don't need the function exists() to see if something exists, from what I see you are using

```
//LogicUnit[exists(Level[@val = 'R'])]
```

where you mean

```
//LogicUnit[Level[@val = 'R']]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the XPath-Expression was just an example. There are a lot of XPath-Expression which need to be evaluated and some of them also using such functions. :-( ...Adding a Namespace-Manager just results in another exception: "XsltContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function."

Answer (score 4):

The XPath function exists() is defined in XPath 2.0, but the default Microsoft XPath engine in .NET only supports XPath 1.0. If you want an XPath 2.0 engine that runs under .NET, try Saxon or XQSharp.

Answer (score 1):

Use <s>//LogicUnit[count(Level[@val = 'R']) > 0].</s>

Comment: the count() > 1 part is pointless there, if you are checking if a count is greater than 0 it is the same as checking that it exists, so that //LogicUnit[Level[@val='R']] produces the same result.